# C# hot reload and breakpoints in VS Code .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

Can someone help me to put work together hot reload and breakpoint in C#, .NET Core 6 in VS Code.

Breakpoints are not working with these settings.

Thanks.

launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    // ...
    {
      // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
      // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
      // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
      "name": "Watch",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
      // "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net6.0/api.dll",
      // "args": [],
      "program": "dotnet",
      "args": [
        "watch",
        "--project",
        ".",
        "--verbose"
      ],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "env": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Attach",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "attach",
      "processId":"${command:pickProcess}"
    }],
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "Debug Hot Reload",
      "configurations": [ "Watch", "Attach" ]
    }    
  ]
}
```

I've tried to use compounds in VS Code but breakpoints are not working.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
            // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
            // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net6.0/api.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            // Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach"
        }
    ]
}
```